# "command not found: pyenv" when called by zsh script

Tags: shell, zsh, pyenv

I have made a launcher on my xubuntu desktop which calls a script named dev_blog.sh.

dev_blog.sh contains :

```
#!/usr/bin/zsh
echo ça marche
pyenv activate zinnia
/usr/bin/zsh
```

When I call the launcher from the desktop, my terminal opens and I can read :

`dev_blog.sh:3: command not found: pyenv`

Whereas when I type the same line in the same terminal, it works.

Here's the content of my .zshrc :

```
export ZSH=/home/proph73/.oh-my-zsh
ZSH_THEME="agnoster"
PATH="$HOME/bin:$HOME/.local/bin:$PATH"
export PYENV_ROOT="$HOME/.pyenv"
export PATH="$PYENV_ROOT/bin:$PATH"
eval "$(pyenv init -)"
eval "$(pyenv virtualenv-init -)"
source $ZSH/oh-my-zsh.sh`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PATH="$HOME/bin:$HOME/.local/bin:$PATH"  move this to your .profile or use the full path to the executable in your shortcut  $(which pyenv)

Comment: Thanks for the answer but it does not change anything.

Comment: Using the full path should work.  The problem genesis is that shortcuts don't run in a shell, and your .zshrc file doesn't get executed by the shortcut.  You could try sourcing the .zshrc from your launcher.   If things still aren't working you can start a log file and print values to be sure things are as expected. echo "path=$PATH" >> /tmp/muhlog.log